# Attempting to display xsl content, but cannot get the grandchild to display

Tags: xml, xslt

I've successfully displayed content for two of the columns however I cannot seem to display any content in the third column.

Namely I want to create a link to the pdf file under the document grandchild.

Here's the xml

```
        <objects>
        <img id="m" modTime="2019-03-07-03:30:19" url="http://qcoast.geosite.com.au/staging/packages/qcoast/GeoPackage882_AIRLIE173_335_.jpg" format="jpg"/>
        <img id="a" modTime="2019-03-07-03:30:19" url="http://qcoast.geosite.com.au/staging/packages/qcoast/GeoPackage_qcoast_882_siting.jpg" format="jpg"/>    
        <floorplan id="1" modTime="2019-03-07-03:30:19" url="http://qcoast.geosite.com.au/staging/packages/qcoast/GeoPackage_qcoast_882_fp1.jpg" format="jpg"/>
        <document id="3" modTime="2019-03-07-03:30:19" title="Brochure" url="http://qcoast.geosite.com.au/staging/packages/qcoast/GeoPackage_qcoast_882.pdf" format="pdf"/>                     

    </objects>
```

and the xsl

```
    <xsl:for-each select="residential">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="headline"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="priceView"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="document"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I've checked the /root/residential/objects/document path via https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html and it returns the correct result for "document" but still cannot get it to display.

Here's the output I get.
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiYHU.png)

Comment: Please post a reproducible example - see: [mcve] - and include the expected output (as code, not a picture).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the path to `document` is  `/root/residential/objects/document` and you are in the context of `residential`, then you need to use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="objects/document"/>
```

to get the value of `document`.

However, in the snippet you have posted, the `document` element has no value. You need to select one of its attributes to get a meaningful result, for example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="objects/document/@url"/>
```

The rest depends on whether there can be more than one `document` selected by this expression, and whether you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was indeed the fact I had not selected an attribute. I've only been coding for 2 days and this was an oversight on my part, but you have helped me learn something. Again thanks.